# Python. Manipulation with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Friends, I have a list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = 
[
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
]
```

I want to create a new list where partial duplicates are eliminated.

In my case this dictionary must be eliminated:

```
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green'}
```

, because it duplicates longer dictionaries:

```
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'}
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
```

Hence, the desired result:

```
[
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
]
```

How to do it? Thanks a million!

Comment: are you mean , if a shorter dictionary is a subset of a longer dictionary ,then filter it out , right ?

Comment: First step is to decide how do you mark something as a partial duplicate. Is it just the key pair occurs more than once?

Comment: @Shawn. yes, sir. That's exactly right!

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Inside the dict, key-value pairs are unique. Between two dictionaries, yes, there are duplicates.

Comment: Can we assume the keys are static? Meaning you know all the possible keys?

Comment: you can make use of `issubset` function, check if a dictionary is a subset of some other dictionary in the list

Answer (score 5):

The first [well, second, with some edits..] thing that comes to mind is this:

```
def get_superdicts(dictlist):
    superdicts = []
    for d in sorted(dictlist, key=len, reverse=True):
        fd = set(d.items())
        if not any(fd <= k for k in superdicts):
            superdicts.append(fd)
    new_dlist = map(dict, superdicts)
    return new_dlist
```

which gives:

```
>>> a = [{'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big'}, {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'fresh'}, {'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'big'}, {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'rotten'}]
>>> 
>>> get_superdicts(a)
[{'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'big'}, 
 {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'rotten'}, 
 {'bananas': 'fresh', 'oranges': 'big', 'apples': 'green'}]
```

[Originally I was using a `frozenset` here, thinking I could do some kind of clever set operation but obviously didn't come up with anything.]

Comment: You could replace `fd.issubset(k)` with `fd <= k`.

Comment: @Blender: good point, edited.  It still feels that there should be some slicker set-based trick.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following implementation

Note in my implementations, I am presorting and selecting only the 2 pair combinations to reduce the number of iterations.
This will ensure that the key is always less or equal in size to the hay

```
>>> my_list =[
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
]

#Create a function remove_dup, name it anything you want
def remove_dup(lst):
    #import combinations for itertools, mainly to avoid multiple nested loops
    from itertools import combinations
    #Create a generator function dup_gen, name it anything you want
    def dup_gen(lst):
        #Now read the dict pairs, remember key is always shorter than hay in length
        for key, hay in combinations(lst, 2):
            #if key is in hay then set(key) - set(hay) = empty set
            if not set(key) - set(hay):
                #and if key is in hay, yield it
                yield key
    #sort the list of dict based on lengths after converting to a item tuple pairs
    #Handle duplicate elements, thanks to DSM for pointing out this boundary case
    #remove_dup([{1:2}, {1:2}]) == []
    lst = sorted(set(tuple(e.items()) for e in lst), key = len)
    #Now recreate the dictionary from the set difference of
    #the original list and the elements generated by dup_gen
    #Elements generated by dup_gen are the duplicates that needs to be removed
    return [dict(e) for e in set(lst) - set(dup_gen(lst))]

remove_dup(my_list)
[{'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'fresh'}, {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'rotten'}, {'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'big'}]

remove_dup([{1:2}, {1:2}])
[{1: 2}]

remove_dup([{1:2}])
[{1: 2}]

remove_dup([])
[]

remove_dup([{1:2}, {1:3}])
[{1: 2}, {1: 3}]
```

---

A faster implementation

```
def remove_dup(lst):
    #sort the list of dict based on lengths after converting to a item tuple pairs
    #Handle duplicate elements, thanks to DSM for pointing out this boundary case
    #remove_dup([{1:2}, {1:2}]) == []
    lst = sorted(set(tuple(e.items()) for e in lst), key = len)
        #Generate all the duplicates
    dups = (key for key, hay in combinations(lst, 2) if not set(key).difference(hay))
    #Now recreate the dictionary from the set difference of
    #the original list and the duplicate elements
    return [dict(e) for e in set(lst).difference(dups)]
```

Comment: @MostafaR: {'a': 'b', 'a': 'b'} is actually {'a': 'b'} and by set theory a set is a subset of itself

Comment: @MostafaR: `{'a': 'b', 'a': 'b'} == {'a': 'b'}`.

Comment: @TorroBuden: If the answer helped, try upvoting and accepting the answer

Comment: I think this code can sometimes remove too many dicts: e.g. `remove_dup([{1:2}]) == [{1: 2}]` but `remove_dup([{1:2}, {1:2}]) == []`.  [This is a corner case, though, and easily fixed.  I mention it only because I was comparing everyone's answers to look for bugs and it asserted.]

Comment: @Abhijit How is the last one faster? You still have a comparable O(N^3) implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one implementation you can use: -

```
>>> my_list = [
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
{'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
]

>>> def is_subset(d1, d2):
        return all(item in d2.items() for item in d1.items())
        # or
        # return set(d1.items()).issubset(set(d2.items()))

>>> [d for d in my_list if not any(is_subset(d, d1) for d1 in my_list if d1 != d)]
[{'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'fresh'}, 
 {'apples': 'red', 'oranges': 'big'}, 
 {'apples': 'green', 'oranges': 'big', 'bananas': 'rotten'}]
```

For each dict `d` in `my_list`: -

```
any(is_subset(d, d1) for d1 in my_list if d1 != d)
```

checks whether, it is a subset of any of the other `dict` in the `my_list`. If it returns `True`, then at least one dict is there, whose subset is `d`. So, we take a `not` of it to exclude `d` from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

```
def is_subset(d1, d2):
    # Check if d1 is subset of d2
    return all(item in d2.items() for item in d1.items())

filter(lambda x: len(filter(lambda y: is_subset(x, y), my_list)) == 1, my_list)
```

Comment: That's really clever, how in the world did you come up with that?

Comment: Your answer is not very different from Rohit's except that you have obscured it by multiple filters

Answer (score 1):

I think it has a better time order:

```
def is_subset(a, b):
    return not set(a) - set(b)

def remove_extra(my_list):
    my_list = [d.items() for d in my_list]
    my_list.sort()

    result = []
    for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
        if not is_subset(my_list[i], my_list[i + 1]):
            result.append(dict(my_list[i]))
    result.append(dict(my_list[-1]))

    return result

print remove_extra([
        {'oranges':'big','apples':'green'},
        {'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'fresh'},
        {'oranges':'big','apples':'red'},
        {'oranges':'big','apples':'green','bananas':'rotten'}
    ])
```